# How to recover my corrupted Document in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: php, wamp, sublimetext2

I am running WAMP on Win7. I was working on a PHP file and everything was fine even after saving. I opened Sublime Text 2 the next day to work on that same file only to find that the document had been corrupted. The contents have been replaced by a bunch binary or hex values. When viewed on my browser that same document simply has the following text shown:

```
[{"uri":"http://localhost/","value":"firebugged.closed"},{"uri":"http://localhost[ project folder here ]/listing.php","value":"firebugged.closed"}]
```

Indeed I have Firebug installed and it is working properly. Is there a way to restore my document? I would really need to recover this, thanks!

Comment: This is why we use version control, folks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're stuck with it. With ST2 on XP, at least, a file's revisions are saved even after saving, so I can open a document, make some changes, save it, and still use `ctrl-z` to undo those changes, **provided** the document hasn't been closed in ST2. However, I don't think changes are saved after you close the document, so I think you're SOL, unless there's a copy somewhere else, perhaps cached on your webserver, or something like that.